# SQL Query - Count number of descendants and summarize with condition

Tags: sql, hierarchy

Consider a table with columns:

| Manager | Manager ID | Headcount | Superior | Superior ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3 | C | 123 |
| B | 2 | 4 | D | 345 |

The table consists of a hierarchy within a company. Each manager has a superior.
The task is to calculate headcount on each level of the hierarchy with the **condition**:

**assign the headcount from the lower branch ONLY if the person has at least 3 or more people directly reporting to him/her and the person on the lower branch is not meeting this criteria**.
This is effectively assigns all the direct reports to the first person that meets the criteria within the hierarchy.

Visual aid to make things clearer:
[image]

I am blocked. I can create a hierarchy with summary telling me what are all the lower levels within that person's hierarchy and what is their respective headcount. However, I fail to see how can I move further from there with SQL.
Code to create hierarchy:

```
cteHeadcount AS
(
 SELECT
  m.manager_id as step_id,
  m.manager_id as id,
  m.superior_id,
  m.headcount,
  m.eligible,
  1 AS step
 FRPM LineMngrs as m
UNION ALL
 SELECT
  c.step_id,
  m.manager_id as id,
  c.superior_id,
  m.headcount,
  m.eligible,
  c.step + 1 as step
 FROM LineMngrs as m
 INNER JOIN cteHeadcount as c ON c.id = m.superior_id
)
```

Thanks for all the help and suggestions!